# On image upload PC freezes for second

Tags: c#

I am making program that takes screenshot and uploads that image on web host via FTP. I have problem, when program uploads image, in that time PC freezes for second, I suppose that second is time while image is uploading. User must not have feeling like something is slowing his PC.

How to eliminate that one second freeze?

**Note:** This is not some type of virus

```
/* Upload File */
public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
{
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        /* Open a File Stream to Read the File for Upload */
        FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Open);
        /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        /* Upload the File by Sending the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
        try
        {
            while (bytesSent != 0)
            {
                ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        localFileStream.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;  
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    return;
}
```

This is my upload function

Comment: Just to check - the PC freezes or just your application?

Comment: Mouse and whole PC :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method declaration:

```
public async Task upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
```

Then change the call to Write:

```
await ftpStream.WriteAsync(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
```

The rest of the I/O in the method is probably fast enough to not require switching to the async/await approach. But you might consider switching those over as well.

Note that you will have to change the call-site for `upload()` as well. You'll need to "bubble-up" the async/await pattern all the way to the initial UI event handler, which can be `async void` instead of `async Task` (so that you can match the required event-handler method signature).

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you call your `upload()` method, use `Task` to run it asynchronously:

```
var task = new Task(() =>
{
    upload(remotePath, localPath);
});
task.Start();
```

If you need to report something back to the UI thread, while the task is running.... progress, for example, simply use the `Dispatcher`:

```
var task = new Task(() =>
{
    upload(remotePath, localPath);
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    new Action(() =>
    {
        DoSomethingToUI();
    }));
});
task.Start();
```

It works well for me and there's no need to "bubble-up" async back to anyone.